# Load custom formatted comment with AJAX: reply link isn’t rendered?

Tags: ajax, comments

I'm submitting comments with AJAX and then loading it on response. Long story short it all works fine except reply link isn’t being rendered on the page. As I understand, the problem is can’t pass `$args` to it. How would I access `$args` or `max_depth` outside the callback?

Callback function:

```
 function prefix_format_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
 $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
 ?> 

     <div class="comment" id="comment-<?php echo $comment->ID; ?>"

     ...Comment code – not published here for brevity...

     <?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array(
            'reply_text' => 'Reply'
            'depth'      => $depth,
            'max_depth'  => $args['max_depth']
        ) ) ); ?>

    </div>

 <?php 
 }
```

Comment handling function (some parts are removed for brevity)

```
function prefix_submit_ajax_comment(){
    $comment = wp_handle_comment_submission( wp_unslash( $_POST ) );

    ...handle errors and get $comment_depth...

    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    $GLOBALS['comment_depth'] = $comment_depth;

    op_format_comment($comment, $args, $comment_depth); // how to pass args here???



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you can get `max_depth` from the options via `get_option('thread_comments_depth')`:

```
function prefix_submit_ajax_comment(){
    $comment = wp_handle_comment_submission( wp_unslash( $_POST ) );

    ...handle errors and get $comment_depth...

    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    $GLOBALS['comment_depth'] = $comment_depth; 
    $args['max_depth'] = get_option( 'thread_comments_depth' ); // solution 

    op_format_comment($comment, $args, $comment_depth);
}
```