# Loading comments in ajax - comment-reply function missing $args

Tags: ajax, comments

I'm loading comments with AJAX.
It all works fine except reply link isn’t being rendered on the page. As I understand, the problem is can’t pass $args. How would I access $args or max_depth outside the callback?

Ajax template :

```
<?php
    require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );

    if (isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id']) {
        $comments = get_comments(array('post_id' => $_POST['id']));
        
        foreach ($comments as $comment) {            
            $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
        ?>
            <div class="comment">
                <?php comment_text(); ?>
                <div class="comment__reply">
                    <?php 
                    comment_reply_link ( 
                            array_merge( 
                                    $args, 
                                    array( 
                                        'reply_text' => __( 'Répondre ', 'autourdesanimaux' ), 
                                        'depth' => $depth, 
                                        'max_depth' => get_option( 'thread_comments_depth' ) 
                                    ) 
                            ) 
                    );
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }
    } ?>
```

This code is not recognized (I am in a custom ajax)

```
array_merge( 
        $args, 
        array( 
            'reply_text' => __( 'Répondre ', 'autourdesanimaux' ), 
            'depth' => $depth, 
            'max_depth' => get_option( 'thread_comments_depth' ) 
        ) 
)
```

Thank you

This post doesn't explain how to access $args
[Load custom formatted comment with AJAX: reply link isn’t rendered?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/286775/load-custom-formatted-comment-with-ajax-reply-link-isn-t-rendered)

Comment: You shouldn't be loading WP in a standalone PHP file, it's extreme bad practice, it's insecure, fragile, and has lots of other problems. If you need to make AJAX calls use the REST API to handle them, or at least the old admin AJAX API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need an existing `$args` variable here, you can define your own arguments and they will override the defaults. See the [get_comment_reply_link() docs for the defaults](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_reply_link/).

Instead, you can pass the arguments you want directly.

```
    comment_reply_link( array(
        'reply_text' => __( 'Répondre ', 'autourdesanimaux' ),
        'depth'      => $depth,
        'max_depth'  => get_option( 'thread_comments_depth' )
    ) );
```

The `$depth` variable will need to be set, and it needs to be greater than zero and less than `max_depth`. [This article describes how to get a comment's depth](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/get-comment-depth.html) by checking for the `parent` property on `WP_Comment` objects and counting.

Comment: Thank you Andrew ! It works with your code and the solution you linked for the depth :-)